# MailKit not download all attachments?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mailkit

I developed a job in .NET Core 2 that collect the .xml's attachments in a specific e-mail, using MailKit. The code is bellow:

```
public List<string> GetXmls()
{
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    for (int nEmail = 0; nEmail < exchange.Count; nEmail++)
    {
        try
        {
            var mensagem = exchange.GetMessage(nEmail);

            foreach (MimePart attachment in mensagem.Attachments)
            {
                if (attachment.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        xmlPaths.Add(DownloadXml(attachment));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Aviso(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
        }
    }

    return xmlPaths;
}

public string DownloadXml(MimePart attachment)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(@"", $"Attachments\\xml_{DateTime.Now.ToString(_formatoData)}.xml");

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        attachment.Content.DecodeTo(memoryStream);

        using (var stream = File.Create(path))
        {
            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(memoryStream.ToArray());

                Log.Debug($"Attachment {attachment.FileName} - Downloaded with success");
            }
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

The code runs normally in my machine, I sended two e-mails with 77 xmls in total and the code downloaded all xmls. But when I try to run the .exe in a server the job download only a some xmls. I runned it a several times, sometimes the job downloaded 20 xml, sometimes 25, 27, it's intermittent.

The most bizarre thing is that the log printed "Downloaded with success" 77 times, all time that I runned the job, and no one exception is throwed.

I tested in 5 machines, 2 worked normally (mine, with .NET Core SDK installed and my friend's PC, without .NET Core SDK installed, both are Win 10 x64) and other 3 worked with this problem (1 PC is Win7 x64 and the other 2 are Windows Server 2008 R2, all of then without .NET Core SDK installed).

The way I published the JOB is by .net cli: **dotnet publish -c release -r win7-x64 --self-contained**

Sorry for my bad english, brazilian here! :)

Comment: `Log.Aviso(ex)` is effectively swallowing exceptions. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Use MailKit's [ProtocolLog](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) feature to figure out if the message downloaded from the server contains all of the attachments.

Comment: Also note that `message.Attachments` assumes that the attachments will have a `Content-Disposition` header with a value set to `attachment`. If this is not the case, then the MIME parts that contain your xmls will not be included in the `Attachments` property and you will have to use the `message.BodyParts` property instead.